# Interaction in a repeated measures logistic regression

Tags: logistic, interaction, stata

I want to test for the effect of interaction between two variables using a repeated measures logistic regression but I don't know how.

I am using Stata and the following lines:

```
xtset participant            
xtgee FIRST_VAR SECOND_VAR, fam(binomial) link(logit)
```

Comment: Is this a statistical or a software question?

Comment: It's a little of both... Right now I have generated a new variable called interaction, which is interaction=Variable1*Variable2. But I am not sure that this is the right way to introduce the interaction into my model. Is it? And if it isn't, does Stata "knows" how to generate an interaction variable? And how does it do it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is the right way, and I don't know about Stata.